# Is there any advantage of Redis connection pool over single connection?

Tags: redis, connection, connection-pooling

I am trying to use Redis for my application. In my application multiple user at the same time want to get the data which is stored in redis cache . As Redis is Single-threaded & we can't run operation concurrently against a single server, **by using connection pool can we execute multiple commands at a single time to achieve the high throughput** ?

I have read some of the articles in open forum & they said it would be helpful using connection pooling only when we know we are going to use redis blocking operation some time like BLPOP. But, if we are sure that we are never going to use blocking operations & use only normal operation like SET,MSET, GET & MGET then using connection pooling having any advantage over single connection ?

Also can anybody have any idea/recommendation about the **maximum no of keys** we will need to provide in MGET command in order to get the maximum values of all specified keys ?

It will be very helpful if I get answers to this. Thanks in advance.